# Do we need a national anthem?

Tags: discussion, fun

Since there are over 4.8 million (4.3m on SO, 211k on SF, 330k on SU) users on the original trinity alone, Stack Exchange is the size of a small country. (More than [Costa Rica](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population)) Even small countries have national anthems, therefore **Stack Exchange should have a national anthem**.

1. Do we need one?
2. Should we have one?
3. Who should write it?

And most importantly:

4. How many implicit references should it have?

Edit: This was tagged with [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) please treat it as such.

Comment: We (in my country) had a similar contest for the song for the King a couple of years back. From that experience I don't think songs should be crowd-sourced....

Comment: Idea is reasonable, but are you going to pay for it?

Comment: Stack Exchange has 6 flags. How many has any other country?

Comment: do facebook  needs to be declared as country than ?

Answer (score 13):

Stack Exchange may be as large as a small country; this doesn't make it a small country.

Comment: New York City and Mexico City are even larger than Stack Exchange, and neither have an anthem either. :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 WHAT? [New York, New York](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KJQNMqVIug) isn't the anthem of that city?

Comment: Brilliant metaphor. I want this on my tee shirt.

Comment: yeah Its nice :)

Answer (score 0):

Think of England (doesn't have a national anthem) and are they pretty big to deal with. But those sports team Like football do have.

Comment: Umm we do...? God save the Queen?

Comment: @Tim *Technically*, [we don't](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_anthem_of_England), Britain does. But yeah... not the best example! :P

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ well yah... But Britain only exists because of England planting flags around the world :P There is a county with no anthem I just can't remember atm